# Using yield in nested loop

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{
    "id": 123,
    "sports": {
        "football": {
            "amount": 3,
            "count": 54
        },
        "baseball": {
            "amount": 4,
            "count": 67
        }
    }
}]
result = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in data[i]['sports']:
        row = data[i]['sports'][j]
        row['kind'] = j
        row['id'] = data[i]['id']
        result.append(row)

result = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(result)
```

> ```
>    amount  count      kind   id
> 0       3     54  football  123
> 1       4     67  baseball  123
> ```

I'm studying how to use yield command to save memory.

How can I use yield in the loop to get the same result?

(Like changing `result.append(row)` to `yield result`)

Comment: I don't know that you can save memory in this way since you have to hold it all in your dataframe anyway.

Comment: Perhaps read the tutorial on generators first. Adding a yield statement to your program won't magically reduce your memory footprint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've been told in the comments, I also don't think you can save memory using yield in this case. However, if you only want to know how to use yield, this is one of the options:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{
    "id": 123,
    "sports": {
        "football": {
            "amount": 3,
            "count": 54
        },
        "baseball": {
            "amount": 4,
            "count": 67
        }
    }
}]
result = []


def yield_data(sports):
    for sport_name, sport_item in sports.items():
        yield sport_item, sport_name


for d in data:
    for row, row['kind'] in yield_data(d['sports']):
        row['id'] = d['id']
        result.append(row)

result = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(result)
```